# Can I turn a Pyspark-SQL groupby into a dataframe? I need to join it later

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a groupby that I want to have as a pyspark dataframe, as I need to join the resulting data with another dataset that I have.

So basically, I just want this table to be a dataframe that I can perform dataframe operations on.

| DATE | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 01/12/2019 | 583 |
| 02/14/2020 | 421 |

`crash_orig.groupBy('Date').count().sort(desc('count')).show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use assignment operator to save the dataframe by declaring a variable:

```
df = crash_orig.groupBy('Date').count().sort(desc('count'))
df.show()
```